# How to get Oracle Stored Procedure result set metadata in JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, metadata, sys-refcursor

I have few Oracle Stored Procedure returning SYS_REFCURSOR.
The result set from each SP is different i.e, each stored procedure returns different number of fields and types.
The Java application is using JPA/Hibernate to get the result using StoredProcedureQuery getResultList() API. This is returning an object array (Object[]).
Is there any way to get the meta data for the resultset?
I'm looking for something similar to JDBC ResultSetMetaData but for JPA2/Hibernate.